# AWS S3: access denied (403) despite having a `READ` grant on an object's ACL

Tags: amazon-s3, acl

**Problem summary**

A role from a different account (`Account2` in the description below) can't read an S3 object, despite having `"Permission": "READ"` grant set, as seen in the object's ACL below.

**Question**

What else could prevent the role from `Account2` from accessing the S3 object?

**Problem description**

There are 3 accounts:

- `Account1` **owns the bucket**, which has ownership settings "ACLs enabled" and "Bucket owner preferred";
- `Account2`'s role *can't* **read** from it (the problem);
- `Account3`'s Lambda **puts** object into it, but doesn't specify any ACL.

Access to an object is denied from a role in `Account2`, *despite it having `"READ"` permission*, as seen in the following object's ACL. The role is assumed by EC2 and has the necessary permissions (`"s3:*"`, with a `"Deny"` for `"Delete*"` operations).

```
# object's ACL
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "Account3",
        "ID": "333"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "Account2",
                "ID": "222",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unless mistaken, an S3 bucket's ACL doesn't impact object's ACL. In any case, the (denied) reader `Account2` has a `"READ"` ACL on the bucket as well:

```
# bucket ACL
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "Account1",
        "ID": "111"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "Account2",
                "ID": "222",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        }
    ]
}
```

These are the bucket- and account-level settings regarding "public" access:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does your IAM Role in `Account2` have an IAM policy attached that explicitly allows access to the S3 bucket it's trying to access, i.e. S3 bucket of `Account1`? That might be needed to allow the Role to have access to the bucket you're trying to access.

Refer to the [policy evaluation logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow) in AWS.